# Configure loki.yaml

Tags: azure-devops, devops, grafana-loki

I am new to Loki and I was able to setup loki stack on kubernates cluster using helm. I have following questions

1. how can I edit loki.yaml configuration to load bigger chunk of data? right now loki/grafana does not load logs older than 1 hr sometimes its 15,45 mins
2. if I edit loki.yaml from kubernates dashboard how can I restart the pod to use updated configurations or which service should I restart?
3. how long does promtail wait to send updated state of pods. for example if a new pod is created how log loki will take to show new pod in grafana. do we have any config property for it as well?
4. Is there any better log aggregation tool ?

Thanks